# Python GridSearchCV smote otimization error

Tags: python, smote

Can anyone help me with an error I am receiving when running grid search. I can't resolve this error.

My code:

```py
# get feature and label data
feature_data = creditcard_data.loc[:, creditcard_data.columns != 'Class']
label_data = creditcard_data.loc[:, creditcard_data.columns == 'Class']

from imblearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from imblearn.pipeline import make_pipeline
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

pipe = make_pipeline(
    SMOTE(),
    LogisticRegression()
)

pipe.get_params().keys()

weights = np.linspace(0.005, 0.05, 10)

gsc = GridSearchCV(estimator=pipe,
                   param_grid={
                       # 'smote__ratio': [{0: int(num_neg), 1: int(num_neg * w) } for w in weights]
                       'smote': weights},
                   scoring='f1',
                   cv=3)

grid_results = gsc.fit(testdf_feature, testdf_label)

print("Best parameters : %s" % grid_result.best_params_)

# Plot the weights vs f1 score
dataz = pd.DataFrame({'score': grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score'],
                      'weight': weights})
dataz.plot(x='weight')
```

I am getting this error:

> TypeError: All intermediate steps of the chain should be estimators that implement fit and transform or fit_resample (but not both) or be a string 'passthrough' '0.005' (type ) doesn't)

Comment: Can you reformat you question please.

Comment: Sorry about the formating, it was my first time. I will try do better in the next time